# What command-line software is there for fully automatic image morphing?

Tags: image-processing, command-line

I would like to create morphing animations (transition of shape and color) of a set of images and I would like to do it from the command-line. Also, I don't want to specify keypoints or such because I need the process to be fully automatic. What software is there that can do that?

Comment: Great tool, but a rule of this site is that you can not post a question about software that you have already developed. The order should be: 1) You have a need 2) You post the question 3) If no solution is posted, develop your own software 4) Post it as a solution to your initial question. Thanks! :-)